# detail view near list view with django

Tags: python, django, listview, message, detailview

I have this message list view rendere with a function that return template name, message list, message count.
Now I need to show the message detail when I click on a message preview on the left.
How can I reach this in django? 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DllUd.png)

Comment: make an ajax call and handle the return

Comment: ajax call onclick right? and then I pass the pk to a view that will render the queryset?

Comment: and pass json back which you can then display through javascript